# yaml and compiling libYaml for python under windows

Tags: python, windows, yaml, pyyaml, libyaml

I'm wish to write&read data files ( big size 10mb+ ), I'm thinking about using using yaml for that.
But, after some testing, seems that yaml is extremely slow in both write and read for file that size. Than I read about libYaml C++, that speed things up for using yaml.CLoader.

I'm using Windows7 64bit and I couldn't find any installer for libYaml, so I rolled out my sleeves and tried ( for the first time ever ) compiling the source (using VS2008).
I mange to compile the output yaml.dll. but that's not the file type I need for python to import/use , I need *.pyd so I got stuck at this point and could use some help :)

Any idea how can I compile libYaml for win64bit and python?
Or
What's you're favorite writer/reader of big size dictionary-like files ( where speed and human-readability matters )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get a 64 bit windows installer here (not me):

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: see also code example in http://pyyaml.org/ticket/34 for how to better switch to the CLoader. the ticket is from six years ago and still an issue.

Comment: This link leads to a "page not found"

Comment: It may no longer be relevant, but here is his updated page (note that I have never met him or even talked to him online, and I'm sure he makes no guarantees these will be available tomorrow, etc. but I really appreciate his efforts over the years!) ...
https://www.cgohlke.com

Answer (score 0):

libyaml is the C library that contains the parsing and emitting code (the transformation steps closest to the  YAML document. You probably get a `.dll` from that like you get a `.so` on Linux.

PyYAML has some C functions to bind the non-python-specific libyaml to calls that allow python to work with libyaml (it is really a thin layer).

You can download an installer for Windows for your platform width (32/64)bit and the appropriate Python version from the [PyYAML installation page](http://www.pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML)